# storm-kafka integration error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am getting below error: the curator jars are referring to server classpath, which is mapr lib and it includes curator jars.

I am not packaging the curator jars in final executable jar.
Please help in fixing this issue::

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.utils.ZKPaths.mkdirs(Lorg/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper;Ljava/lang/String;ZLorg/apache/curator/utils/InternalACLProvider;Z)V
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:726) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$11.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:703) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107) ~[curator-client-2.7.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:700) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:477) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:44) ~[curator-framework-2.9.0.jar:?]
        at storm.kafka.ZkState.writeBytes(ZkState.java:76) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.ZkState.writeJSON(ZkState.java:70) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.commit(PartitionManager.java:276) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpoutOld.commit(KafkaSpoutOld.java:203) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpoutOld.nextTuple(KafkaSpoutOld.java:164) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:39) ~[stormjar.jar:0.3-SNAPSHOT]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4615$fn__4630$fn__4661.invoke(executor.clj:610) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-mapr-1611.jar:0.10.0-mapr-1611]
        at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__544.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0-mapr-1611.jar:0.10.0-mapr-1611]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Curator jar versions are out of sync. You're using curator-client 2.7 with curator-framework 2.9. Make sure all your Curator jars are the same version.